# For using custom domian to access the bluemix application directly

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to use custom domain to access my bluemix application directly by registered own domain. So godaddy requires the name server of bluemix so how can i find it or can you know
the another way to access it directly by registered domain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternate way by which you can route your app to your webpage  :

1 : Below your app name you would see the "Routes" with your bluemix url. At the end you have the option to edit the routes. Click that.
[image]
2: A popup would appear with one option as "Manage Domains". Click that. Alternate you can also reach to that page by clicking "Manage organization".

3: On the landing page you have the option to add a new domain. Add your website name here.[image]

4: Now again go to edit routes. And add new route. You would see your website's name appearing . Add a name to your app. suppose you gave "myapp" as the name and your webpage name is "mywebsite.com" then your app would be redirected to your subdomain named "myapp.mywebsite.com". On save you can see this new route appearing additional to your existing routes for your app.

This is the first part. Now go to your domain provider and add create new alis with the app name. "myapp.mywebsite.com" and pass the alis name as the actual route provided by bluemix to you. Once done your app would be visible at your website.

Comment: i don't want like myapp.mywebsite.com i only want like mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

You could follow what suggested by @Manish but instead of creating an alias CNAME on your DNS configuration you could create an A record pointing one of the following IP

US-SOUTH: 75.126.81.68
EU-GB: 5.10.124.142
AU-SYD: 168.1.35.169

according to the region your application is running on.