# What is the best way to use a custom domain name with IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I was wondering how developers go about using IBM Bluemix with custom domain names, and how you go about registering your DNS information.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question has been answered here ?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606447/1295822

Answer (score 6):

Bluemix supports custom domains and SSL certs.  You can even use wildcard and SAN certs as well.

To use a custom domain you need to register the domain in the [Bluemix UI](http://bluemix.net).  Once you login click on your organization name on the left and click on "Manage Organizations".

Find your organization and click domains. Enter in the domain of your choosing.

The next step is creating a DNS record for Bluemix.

Create an A record for whatever host you want, for example `.` for the root domain of your domain.  You can also create an A record for `*` so all requests all routed to Bluemix.

The A record needs to point to `75.126.81.68` for the US-South Instance.

For the EU-GB region in London you need to create an A record that points to `5.10.124.141`.

Comment: Not to be a besserwisser but you have a typo in your answer!

The right IP to EU-GB is: 5.10.124.141

Answer (score 0):

The good news is Bluemix supports custom domains which you have to configure in the Bluemix management dashboard.   To do this you should follow these easy steps:

1. Login to the Bluemix admin dashboard
2. Go to the 'Manage Your Organization' tab in the dashboard
3. Click on the domains admin link to open the domain management UI
4. Enter your domain name (you need to have registered this domain already and have access to the DNS settings).
5. Login to your DNS management dashboard and set your DNS settings:
   a. Create an A-RECORD for the home domain *.domain.com
   b. Set the A-RECORD to your instance IP (you can find this on the admin page)
   c. Commit and save the changes
6. This will take up to 48-hours to propagate, but you can test it within 30-min.